# how to configure settings.xml in jenkins pipleline goovy file?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I have my own `settings.xml` in my workspace which will help me in getting the jars from a repo
Now I want to configure this settings.xml in the Jenkins pipeline file, how can I do that?

where/how should I add the `settings.xml` in the groovy file? Can someone help me with the command which will help in configuring the `settingns.xml`

```
stage('Run') {
        steps {
               echo 'Running....'
               sh """#!/bin/bash -e
                      pwd
                      ls -al
                      cd sanity
                      mvn clean test pom.xml
                      ls -al """
             }
           }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `settings` flag with your maven command.

```
mvn clean build --settings settings.xml
```